# Don't submit form after calling Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this problem:

my HTML code:

```
<form name="addUser" method="post" action="../src/process_register.php">
    ....
    <button type="submit" onClick="formhash_register(this.form);">Submit</button>
</form>
```

my JavaScript code:

```
function formhash_register(form) 
{
var username = form.inputUsername.value;

if(username == "")
        return false;
    else
        form.submit();
}
```

Although my function returns false, you will go to another page, and thats not what I wanted.
Is there way to cancel submit process when the submit button is pressed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <button type="submit" 
      onClick="return formhash_register(this.form);">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Just have in mind that javascript can be disabled, so preventing submission is not 100% bulletproof. Always validate user input on server too.

Answer (score 0):

Change type to "button" which shouldn't automatically submit this form.

```
<button type="submit" onClick="formhash_register(this.form);">Submit</button>
```