# Joomla Site - have a form that calls a javascript function - but it also is redirecting my url - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, joomla

the code:

javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function scroll(pos)
{
    var x = location.hash;
     var scrolamount = pos;
    console.log(scrolamount);
    $('html, body').animate(
    {
        scrollTop: scrolamount
    }, 400);
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.style.height = "101%";
    d.style.overflow = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(d);
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
    }, 100);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

html

this function shows the alert and then returns to page as normal

```
<div id="tester">
<form action="javascript:alert('action sent');" >
<input type="submit" value="But1">
 </form>
```

this form scrolls the page as expected but then immediately redirects the URL to the main page

```
<div id="but1">
 <form  onsubmit="scroll(400)" >
<input type="submit" value="But1">
          </form>       
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't submit form after calling Javascript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124564/dont-submit-form-after-calling-javascript-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not preventing the form to submit. Try adding this :

```
onsubmit="scroll(400); return false;"
```

Comment: that did it - thank you can you explain why or reference something so i understand why this works?

Comment: You could also do `return scroll(400)` because the function returns false. Or even better, don't use inline event handlers at all.

Comment: @morty346 Basically, `onsubmit` attribute is an event handler. Element like form have a default behavior. The form is sending data to a page specified inside the `action` attribute, redirecting the browser. Default behavior can be prevented by `event.preventDefault`, but inline handler can't access it. Retruning false on the other and will `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`(search those termd if you want to know). Usualy, an experienced developer will never use inline action. It is a really bad practice.

Comment: @Juhana What if the function `scroll()` return something? You can't know, hence why I used `return false`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon The function is in the question. It has only one return point and it returns false.

Comment: @Juhana I don't know why i did not see that... My bad.